# Passing '@' symbol to mailto field, or how to bypass URL encoding

Tags: html, google-apps-script, urlencode, mailto

I'm trying to specify a mailto link in an HTML template, for a Google Apps script. Unfortunately, the link:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">
```

is converted to

```
<a href="mailto:foo%40bar.com">
```

because of the processing involved.

How would I return the correct mailto link?

More simply when I do return HTML via a call:

```
function doGet(request) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<a href="foo@bar.com">mail me</a>');
}
```

the returned HTML is:

```
<a target="_parent" href="mailto:foo%40bar.com">mail me</a>
```

which is OK for some mail applications (Mac Mail) but is not the standard.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you provided the template/the part of the template.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ideal answer that I was hoping for but it is a solution to the problem. As is turns out if you have Caja processor evaluate your HTML in Native mode, it won't do this '@' -> '%40' translation.

```
return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
```